# SWI-Prolog backtracking on a web site

Tags: web, prolog

I want to create an expert system using Prolog. The main requirement is to use SWI-Prolog. I've already created some pages for my service. I want to use backtracking to generate the questions, but in Prolog, the user is required to enter a semicolon to finish a query. I want to know how to use backtracking on a web site created with SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Maybe fail? But i think that it will stop backtracking and will show only one solution or not?

Comment: How are you interfacing to SWI Prolog from your web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the SWI-Prolog pengines package.  Pengines runs your query in a separate thread and provides an interface to the web server that allows controlling I/O and backtracking from the web client.  See http://pengines.swi-prolog.org for a life system. Note that pengines are based on SWI-Prolog version 7 (the development version).

P.s. `false` replaced the swi-prolog with prolog.  This question however is pretty system dependent.

Comment: The question is about "to use backtracking for questions generating" instead of putting ";". That is entirely independent of any Prolog system.